# Similar rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, similarity

I'm trying to select the top ten most similar properties for a given property in a realty site and I wondering if you guys could help me out. The variables I'm working with would be price(int), area(int), bathrooms(int), bedrooms(int), suites(int), parking(int). At the moment I'm thinking of ordering by ABS(a-b) but wouldn't that be slow if I had to calculate that every time a property is viewed? (I'm not sure I could cache this since the database is constantly being updated) Is there another option?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are worried about the speed of it, could you not add it as another field, and key it updated.  Perhaps via a trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to create a new table containing the result ready. Like this:-

```
property_id    similar_properties_ids
--------------------------------------
1              2,5,8
2              3,10
...
...
```

And a cron running at regular intervals doing the calculation for all the properties and filling up the `similar_properties_ids`.

So, at runtime, you don't have the calculation overhead but the downside is that you get results which are a little old (updated during the last cron run).

Comment: That database structure isn't helpful - it would be better to keep the IDs of the similar properties in separate rows of a table.

Comment: this table is just for collecting the IDs of related properties at runtime. The original tables storing the properties is intact. When the IDs are there, then if any information about the related properties is needed, those actual tables can be queried using these IDs. You can create one row each for similar_properties_id for every property_id in this table but then your updation and retrieval queries become a little complex.